# How do I open the default mail program with a Subject and Body in Gradle?

Tags: java, android, email, gradle

I am trying to create a Gradle-task,depends on assembleRelease Task.
It will prepare a mail, based on the generated release-APK's path, and open it in default mail program.

I have searched a lot about it and found out that Java's Desktop-API can do this.

But when I am trying to use it in Gradle script, It is giving following error:

> Unable to resolve class Desktop

Is it possible to create such a "Mail" task in Gradle script?

Answer (score 0):

Write code to open Email app by specifying the properties in your `gradle.properties`

Access the properties by below code

```
Properties prop = new Properties();
InputStream input = null;

try {

    input = new FileInputStream("gradle.properties");

    // load a properties file
    prop.load(input);

    // get the property value and print it out
    System.out.println(prop.getProperty("user.password"));
} catch (IOException ex) {
    ex.printStackTrace();
}
```

Check out this [tutorial](http://www.mkyong.com/java/java-properties-file-examples/)

Comment: I want to open default mail program with pre-filled data using gradle.